# Can I use XML attributes as parameters for an SQL query using R

Tags: sql, xml, r, ms-access

I am using R v3.0.3 32bit and Access 2013.  I have created a database table in Access with two tuples and wish to be able to query the database through R.  The SQL is trivial to do this but the parameters necessary are contained within an XML document.

Is there a way in R to use XML values from a DOM tree as direct input into an SQL query?  I've read post on here which show it can be done in SQL server by programming statements such as SELECT .Value(/////)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [XML package](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/xml) to extract the XML into a data frame and then use various columns as parameters in needed MS Access query:

```
library(RODBC)
library(XML)

# XML IMPORT 
doc<-xmlParse("C:\\Path\\To\\XMLFile.xml")    
xmldf <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//MainNodeElement"))

# MS ACCESS CONNECTION
conn <-odbcDriverConnect('driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
                          DBQ=C:\\Path\\To\\AccessDatabase.accdb')

# LOOP THROUGH ROWS OF XML DF
for (i in 0:nrow(xmldf)) {
    # MODIFY SELECT OR ACTION QUERY TO MEET NEEDS, EVEN ADD PARAMS  
    querydf <- sqlQuery(myconn3, paste0("select * from table1 where param='", 
                        xmldf$colname[i], "'"))
}

close(conn)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and I feel it is very close.  Unfortunately the following error is generated.     07002 - 3010 [Microsoft] [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters Expected 1.       The XML I am after looks like this    <metadata>
<codes class="bip:countries:1.0">
  <code code="ARG">
    <editdetail attribution="Reuters BIP Coding Group" action="confirmed" date="1996-08-20"/>

Comment: Access ODBC is complaining about the where clause. In select SQL query, check to see if string/number has quotes or not as needed. And that XML looks to be attribute-centric, not element-centric as my post assumes. See [xmlAttrs()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/XML/docs/xmlAttrs).

Comment: The line of code  xmldf <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(doc1, "//code"))
Produces a message  edit detail 1,2,3,4,5 when I look at xmldf.  Which is the correct number of data items but no data.  However using  xattrs <- xpathSApply(doc1, "//*/code/@code")
Extracts the data correctly for the query, however it doesn't seem to work in the query.